# on change event a two digit year is converted to current year Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

converting the text box value to date on change event with a two digit year is being considered as the current year

I am clearing out my text box if the user enters a date equal to the current date. 
I have a text box to take a date (06-13-1999) / (06/13/1999) formats. Before I finish entering my 4 digit year since I am using an on Change event Javascript native date function is converting the 2 digit year to current year and clearing my text box.

So I am currently using a condition by splitting the date entered date.split('/')[2] .length = 4 which seems to be tedious since now I need two split functions to allow different date formats.

```
if (dob.split('/')[2].length == 4 || dob.split('-')[2].length == 4)
{
    ndob = new Date(dob);
    ndob = formatdate(ndob);
}
```

Is there any other way of handling this on change event

Comment: You can use a regular expression to split on either `/` or `-` in one command... `split(/[\/-]/)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to handle both cases at the same time:

```
if (dob.split(/\/|-/).length === 4) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of your textbox val, if it is `10` then only execute your code.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    const val = this.value;
    if(val.length===10) {
        console.log('valid date');
    }
})
```

```html
    <input type="text">
```